# Degree of a linear system

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $X$ be a nonsingular projective curve, say over an algebraically closed field $k$ for convenience. My definition of a linear system $\mathfrak{d}$ of degree $d$ on $X$ is a vector subspace of $H^0(X, \mathscr{L})$, where $\mathscr{L}$ is an invertible sheaf on $X$ of degree $d$. The dimension $n = \dim \mathfrak{d}$ is the dimension of this vector subspace minus $1$, corresponding to the morphism $X \to \mathbb{P}^n_k$ defined by $\mathfrak{d}$. (Basepoint-freeness is unnecessary here due to the Curve-to-Projective Extension Theorem.)

I am comfortable with the definition of a degree of an invertible sheaf (via identification with a Weil divisor or via the Hilbert polynomial), but my definition of the degree of a linear system seems to lead to contradictions. For example, the existence of a $g_{1}^d$ is equivalent to saying that there exists an invertible sheaf $\mathscr{L}$ on $X$ with $\deg \mathscr{L} = d$ and $\dim H^0(X, \mathscr{L}) \geq 2$. This seems to suggest that the existence of a $g_1^d$ implies the existence of a $g_1^{d'}$ for any $d' \geq d$, since $\dim H^0(X, \mathscr{L}(D)) \geq \dim H^0(X, \mathscr{L})$ for any effective divisor $D$. However, I also know that a curve of genus $\geq 3$ cannot be both hyperelliptic and trigonal: it cannot have both a $g_1^2$ and a $g_1^3$.

What is wrong with my definitions and/or reasoning?

Comment: It's possible that twisting $\mathscr L$ by $D$ will just add basepoints, i.e. that the elements of $|\mathscr L(D)|$ are just divisors of the form $E + D$ for $E \in |\mathscr L|$. In a situation like this, the associated map to projective space is obtained by removing the base locus, i.e. it's just the map associated to $|\mathscr L|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example of what's going wrong here can be found in $\mathcal{O}(2)$ on $\Bbb P^1$ by taking the space of global sections spanned by $x^2$ and $xy$. Then the map $[x^2:xy]$ is the same as the map $[x:y]$ coming from the global sections of $\mathcal{O}(1)$. The point is that using the curve to projective extension theorem instead of checking that the linear system is base-point free can change what line bundle the map is really from.

To see this more geometrically, taking a subspace of sections is equivalent to projecting the curve embedded in $\Bbb P^N$ by the original linear system onto a smaller-dimensional $\Bbb P^n$. This projection may have a different degree if the linear subspace you project from intersects the curve: the closure of the preimage of a hyperplane in $\Bbb P^n$ under the projection map will include the linear subspace you're projecting from, which will explain the drop in intersection number, i.e. the drop in the degree of the curve.